# GAS/Google Sheets is wrong in the application of insertRows, insertRowAfter, insertRowsAfter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried a few ways to code for insertion of rows, but they give the wrong outputs repeatedly.

In the spreadsheet, when I type IF in cell C2, a blank row should be inserted AFTER the C2 IF.  This happens and is correct. But when I subsequently type IF in cell C3, the GAS interpreter inserted a blank line at the C3 row and pushed the C3 IF to C4.  This should not happen.  It should insert a blank row AFTER the row where the C3 IF was at, but it did not. The same thing happens when I use AND, WHEN and OR.  Each of these have different insertion codes.  There should not be any blank rows between the rows of IF, AND, WHEN and OR.  Is there a solution for this?

I've shared my simplified Google Sheet and the reduced code (a minimal reproducible example) at:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11skN3VLxSqQOqT7NX6tXTUY6kFYivbr9w-Yn2pI4z1s/edit?usp=sharing

And here's the reduced code for ease of analysis:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let c = e.range
  let cvalue = e.value;

  if (cvalue == "IF") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowAfter(c.rowStart);
  }
  if (cvalue == "AND") {
    c.getSheet().insertRows(c.rowStart + 1,1);
  }
  if (cvalue == "WHEN") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowsAfter(c.rowStart, 1);
  }
  if (cvalue == "OR") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowAfter(c.getRowIndex());
  }
}
```

I've also attached 2 pictures: the first of which is what's supposed to happen, and the other is the wrong output because the GAS interpreter malfunctioned:

[image: correct output]
[image: wrong output]

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) focusing on and explaining what inconsistency you are referring to?

Comment: also the output can be the same **or** inconsistent, but it can't be both. which one is it?

Comment: @lamblichus, Ok, I've just reduced my code file to about 35 lines. The link is the same.  Basically in the spreadsheet, I type in IF in cell C3, the checkbox and words "some condition" should appear in the same row as C3, and it does.  A blank row is inserted after the C3 IF, which is correct.  Then I type in IF in cell C4, and the checkbox and words "some condition" should appear in the same row as C4, but it did not.  That's what's wrong.  The GAS interpreter inserted a blank line BEFORE the line where the C4 IF was at, and pushed the C4 IF to C5, when it's not supposed to.

Comment: @lamblichus, It should insert a blank row only AFTER the row where the C4 IF was at, but it did not.  That's what's causing me a lot of problems.  The same thing happens when I use AND, even though the insert code is different.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk, I've updated my sentence to "they give the wrong output repeatedly".  Does this explain better?

Comment: Looks like the engine can't keep up to change the sheet if you're editing faster than one second per cell. I have no solution except to advise don't hurry. And, just in case, if you need to add a row you can press `Ctrl+`

Comment: If what @YuriKhristich said is the issue, you may try `LockService` and `SpreadsheeetApp.flush()` as a means to partially solve the issue

Comment: @YuriKhristich, Thanks, I think the only solution for this coding challenge is to avoid coding with GAS and use manaul entry instead...

Comment: @TheMaster, Thanks, but race conditions are not the cause of this problem, because blank rows were inserted as they should be, but some of them were inserted wrongly.  Just have a look at my updated pictures.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, `Ctrl+` did not work for me, I'm using the Google Chrome browser and what it did was to increase font size.  I'll have to do right click on a cell and select insert row.

Comment: `Ctrl+` should work in Chrome (especially in Chrome!) like a charm. Check the preferences 'Enable compatible shortcuts': https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110

Answer (score 2):

- This is a web user interface bug and  should be reported to Google sheets team through Menu "Help"> "Help Sheets improve". You may add a link to this answer.

#### Sequence of events:

- Selection at C2
- User inputs `IF` in C2 and presses enter
- Selection at C3 after user presses enter button
- Script activates and inserts a new row after C2
- After new row insertion, Old Row 3 is now Row 4
- Selection should be at C4(and it is at C4), but visibly, on the web user interface, the selected border(blue border signifying selection) is at the new Row 3 instead of the old Row 3, which is now Row 4.
- User not knowing that the selection is at C4( because the UI lied that it is at new C3) types something in, but now, UI recognizes it's lie, repents and shows the selection at C4.

#### Workarounds:

- Use <kbd>tab</kbd> instead of  <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Move selection up and down after new row creation
- Automatically select a previous row and a new row using script(`.activateAsCurrentCell()`) to make UI repent soon and seamlessly.

#### Workaround script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const c = e.range
  const cvalue = e.value;
  console.log({rg:c.getA1Notation(),e})

  if (cvalue == "IF") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowAfter(c.rowStart);
  }
  if (cvalue == "AND") {
    c.getSheet().insertRows(c.rowStart + 1,1);
  }
  if (cvalue == "WHEN") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowsAfter(c.rowStart, 1);
  }
  if (cvalue == "OR") {
    c.getSheet().insertRowAfter(c.getRowIndex());
  }
  if(/OR|WHEN|AND|IF/g.test(cvalue)){
   c.activateAsCurrentCell();
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   c.offset(1,0).activateAsCurrentCell()
  };
}
```